# jQuery plugins, scope, and binding a created element to the 'change' event

Tags: jquery-plugins, scope, jquery

So, I'm writing my first plugin.  I'm using the [advice on the jQuery website](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), so my plugin setup looks something like this:

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {
      var $this = $(this);
      // do some code.

      // Add an element
      $this.append('<select id="test"><option value="yes">Yes</option>' +
                   '<option value="no">No</option></select>');

      // Bind the change handler (chose '.on' after reading the documentation for '.delegate')
      $this.on('change', '#test', methods['handler'].call($this, $('#test').val()));

    },
    handler : function( content ) { 
      alert ('You chose: ' + content);
    }
  };

  $.fn.testbed = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

I know that the handler itself is working, because I can substitute

```
function(){ alert ("You did it!");}
```

for the function call, and it works.

But, the way I'm calling the function now doesn't work.  It's how I call other functions from within other methods, but it doesn't work with a handler.

So, my questions are: (1) How do I make it call the function? and (2) is this the best place to set up the handler?

Comment: `But, the way I'm calling the function now doesn't work.` ...and how's that?

Comment: This line in the code above: `$this.on('change', '#test', methods['handler'].call($this, $('#test').val()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id should be unique in the page. Having several elements with the same id will give you a different element from what you think when you try to access it. Don't use an id at all, use `this` in the callback to get the right element.

There is no reason to create a delegate when you are creating one for each event. Bind the event on the select element directly.

The handler for an event should be a function, not the result of a function call.

```
init : function( options ) {

  // Add an element
  this.append('<select><option value="yes">Yes</option>' +
               '<option value="no">No</option></select>');

  // Bind the change handler
  $('select', this).on('change', function() {
    methods['handler']($(this).val());
  });

},
```

Comment: Yah, I'm aware of the proper usage of id's, I just did it that way for the sake of the example.  In the real version, I'm using a class.  I'll give this way a try, thanks!

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering how to get the value of the select box in the 'handler' function if it isn't passed as an argument.  'this' seems to be the jQuery object.

Comment: @coding_hero: If you want the handler to run in the scope of the element (`this` is the DOM element) and not send any parameter to it, you can use `$('select', this).on('change', methods['handler']);` to bind it.